# How to receive different data type with same property name?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I got the requirement that at one API endpoint should be possible to post a json which can look differently.

1.)

```
  "payload": {
     "someJSON" : "something"
  }
```

2.)

```
  "payload": 
    "Hier könnte irgendwelcher Text stehen."
```

I tried to set Payload as a type object, but as soon I put some thing in the payload value the Payload object is not valid anymore, it is null than.

```
    [JsonProperty("payload", Required = Required.AllowNull)]
    public object Payload { get; set; }
```

**How it could be possible to deal with this requirement of different types in one object?**

Comment: Option 3 isn't valid JSON.

Comment: You can't, really. You could potentially use a custom converter to dynamically parse the value and handle it in different ways, but you still ultimately have to push both forms into a single type. JavaScript is duck-typed, so it doesn't complain about this kind of stuff, but C# is strongly-typed, so you must ultimately be able to supply that type, i.e. `string`, regardless of what is sent.